# Integrate code from GitHub

Tags: ios, github, integration

I am working on iOS project & using GitHub. Along with me 2 more developers are working on same project but on different functionality. Now I want to integrate code from all developers. We are using GitHub for FIRST TIME.

Lets say , if they are pushed their code on GitHub independently then how can I get their code & integrate with my code ?

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really depends how your repositories are structured and how you intend to integrate/merge the three repositories together. I'd recommend that you finish / stop development on all three repositories, create a new repository and integrate the three projects manually into the new repository.

Comment: @mauris Thanks for reply. So you mean we need 1 branch for each developer & finally integrate all 3 branches in new branch is it so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have granted those developer the status of collaborator on your repo, that means they can push directly to it.
They can push their features in their own branch, in which case you can be the integrator, and after a `git fetch --all`, start some `git merge` in order to consolidate their work.

But if each developers made its own repo based on your ([called fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)), then they must communicate with your project through [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/).